# How to fix System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user

Tags: c#, connection-string, sql-server-2017

When I run it I get this:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OFtN.png)

I enabled Windows authentication in IIS, SQL Server, and also added the authentication method in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

(I am literally out of ideas...)

As you may see, the DataConnection is running:

[DataConnection Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g94Py.png)

The connection string from `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="cafeaconnection" 
         connectionString="Data source=LENOVO-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial catalog=tipuridecafeaDB; user id=user; password=password; persist security info=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\tipuridecafeaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Error:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user **'Shade'**.]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +907
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +334
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +699
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +443
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   YourCoffeeShop.App_Code.ConnectionClass.GetCafeaByType(String cafeaType) in D:\YCS\YourCoffeeShop\YourCoffeeShop\App_Code\ConnectionClass.cs:29
>   YourCoffeeShop.Pages.Cafea.FillPage() in D:\YCS\YourCoffeeShop\YourCoffeeShop\Pages\Cafea.aspx.cs:26
>   YourCoffeeShop.Pages.Cafea.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\YCS\YourCoffeeShop\YourCoffeeShop\Pages\Cafea.aspx.cs:17
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. It will contain the specific reason for the login failed error, which is not returned to the client for security reasons.

Comment: Also, make sure you have configured SQL Server to allow mixed-mode authentication so that SQL authentication is allowed.

Comment: It is configured that way. As for the log... it goes             :Login failed for user 'Shade'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>] and                                                       Login failed for user 'Lenovo-pc\Shade'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'tipuridecafeaDB'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: Nutshell: _Integrated Authentication_ has a lot to do with [Windows User accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx), and therefore, you have to know what that means from a single server concept, to different servers, all the way to relationships between servers (e.g. `Windows AD/Domains`), and what/how your application's identity is configured (how it will "login" to SQL). Typically, in hosted environments (no AD/Domains), as above, configure mixed-mode (instead).

Comment: The Sql Server is configured mixed-mode. Should i use Sql authentication instead of Windows?

Comment: For the first error, it seems the SQL account `Shade` has not been added as a login to the server. For the "Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'tipuridecafeaDB'" error using Windows auth, it seems `Lenovo-pc\Shade` has not been added as a user to that database.

Comment: I fixed the issue deleting the AAD Admin and creating it back again on the Azure SQL Server.

Comment: I hit issue. The problem was the port number not being included in the `server` part of the db connection string. It was `server=database-name` when it should have been `server=database-name,1434`

Answer (score 0):

Check in service some mssql server services may have stopped. I was also having same issue now it is resolved after starting it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The post is 3+ years old. When posting answer in these posts, consider direct your solution to other that may come across this question instead of OP. OP also mentioned the issue had resolved in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430864/how-to-fix-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user/68700061#comment109585008_50430864).